# terminal closing when ssh connection breaks

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal, panel, mate

This is a new issue for me, where I have a terminal open, with ssh running. But because I live in the backwoods of maine, my sessions frequently break.

formerly, ssh would report, "Broken Pipe" and the terminal window would stay open. That was great, because I could just look, and go ok, and log back in.

Now, for some reason, the entire window closes. This introduces, an extra step into something that was already obnoxious.

I launch the sessions from mate panel, which in turn launches gnome-terminal
(why not mate- terminal? Ive asked, and never got a serious answer)
and then launched the ssh connection. I have to enter passwords.. just because.

So, how can I make my terminal not close, even if ssh suffers from a broken pipe?

Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open terminal first, then start a session from there.

Obviously if you start a session this way, the terminal closes after the session is ended.

You can set up the command to launch the terminal this way:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"ssh root@192.168.1.1; exec bash\""
```

This way after the session ends, `bash` will stay.

You can use another terminal instead of `gnome-terminal`. And you can use `sh` instead of `bash` to load the default shell.

Comment: But I never formerly had to do that.

Comment: It is hard to guess how did you set it up "formerly" and what has happened since.

Comment: is there an option to not close the terminal after the session ends?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @j0h Yes there is such an option under Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Command.

Comment: @egmont This could be an answer too.